# I need to obtain JSON with data extracted from an HTML document

Tags: php, html, json, domdocument

Im trying to make the company phonelist with image, name and phone numbers into a JSON files. I have tried to loop through all `<a>` to find the `img src` and the `div.employee-desc` text, but without success. And I have tried with `DOMdocument()`, but with also with failure.

```
<section>
        <a href="tel:+471234567890">
        <article class="clearfix">
          <div class="employee-image">       
            <img src"image_1.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="employee-desc">
            Emma doe <br>
            +471234567890
          </div>
        </article>
        </a>
        <a href="tel:+471234567890">
        <article class="clearfix">
          <div class="employee-image">       
            <img src"image_2.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="employee-desc">
            Frank doe <br>
            +471234567890
          </div>
        </article>
        </a>
        <a href="tel:+xxxxxxxx">
        <article class="clearfix">
          <div class="employee-image">       
            <img src"image_3.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="employee-desc">
            John doe <br>
            +471234567890
          </div>
        </article></a>
    </section>
```

My dream would be so the json file looked like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "image":"image_1.jpg",
      "name":"Emma doe",
      "phone":"+47 1234567890"
   },
   {  
      "image":"image_2.jpg",
      "name":"Frank doe",
      "phone":"+47 1234567890"
   },
   {  
      "image":"image_3.jpg",
      "name":"John doe",
      "phone":"+47 1234567890"
   }
]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get this done in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the code below.
Please note that the img tag is incorrect in your example. It should be 'img src=""' not 'img src""'

I assume that your html is in $html variable.

```
$json_arr = array();

$html = substr($html, strpos($html, '<section>') + 9);
$html = substr($html, 0, strpos($html, '</section>'));

$arr = explode('<a href="', $html);
foreach ($arr as $k => $line) {
    if ($k == 0) continue;

    $phone = substr($line, 0, strpos($line, '"'));
    $phone = str_replace('tel:', '', $phone);
    $phone = trim($phone);

    $image = substr($line, strpos($line, '<img src="') + 10);
    $image = substr($image, 0, strpos($image, '"'));

    $name = substr($line, strpos($line, '<div class="employee-desc">') + 37);
    $name = substr($name, 0, strpos($name, '</div>'));
    $name = trim($name);
    $name = substr($name, 0, strpos($name, '<br'));

    $json_arr[$k - 1]['image'] = $image;
    $json_arr[$k - 1]['name'] = $name;
    $json_arr[$k - 1]['phone'] = $phone;
}

$json = json_encode($json_arr);
echo $json . "\n";
```

Comment: It looks like some characters are getting escaped like [{"image":"image\/1.jpg","name":"Alexandri Sekj\u00e6r","phone":"62111776"}

Comment: It's probably because of:
1) your target image is in 'image' folder. 'image/1.jpg'  2) The name is in UTF-8 encoding: 'Alexandri Sekjær'

This is just fine. When you decode the JSON, it will be normal.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter approach with the help of [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/):

```
$html = HtmlDomParser::str_get_html($data);

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    $image=$element->children(0)->children(0)->children(0)->src;
    list($name,$phone)=array_map('trim', explode('<br>',$element->children(0)->children(1)->innertext));
    $row = (object)compact('image','name','phone');
    $result[]=$row;
}

$output=json_encode($result,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```